# Ложный результат при использовании авторазмерных ячеек CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Вывожу информацию через CollectionCell, и есть необходимость использования авторазмера для каждой ячейки. Написал алгоритм, но почему-то при больших размерах строки, широта выдается неверной. Вот скриншот как это происходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код, который отвечает за авторазмер ячеек

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if let messageText = messages?[indexPath.item].text {
            let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1000)
            let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
            let customFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)


            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: customFrame.height + 20)
        }

        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "msg", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.bubbleView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        cell.bubbleView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        cell.msgTextField.text = messages?[indexPath.item].text

        cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1)

        if let messageText = messages?[indexPath.item].text, let profileImageName = messages?[indexPath.item].friend?.profileImageName {

            cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: profileImageName)
            cell.profileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            cell.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 15
            cell.profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = true

            let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1000)
            let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
            let customFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)], context: nil)

            cell.msgTextField.frame = CGRect(x: 40 + 8, y: 0, width: customFrame.width + 16, height: customFrame.height + 20)
            cell.bubbleView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: customFrame.width + 8 + 16, height: customFrame.height + 20)
            cell.profileImage.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 32, height: 32)


        }

        return cell
}
```

Не могли бы вы помочь решить данный баг или же предложить другой алгоритм нахождения размеров ячейки. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Если я правильно понял что view в вашем коде это корневой view viewcontrollerа в котором лежит collectionview, то почему вы его ширину используете в CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1000)? У вас же надпись заведомо меньше должна быть из-за иконки и отступов, а вы когда вызываете NSString.boundingRect сообщаете ей что вся ширина в ее распоряжении, да еще потом и сверху докидываете в ширину надписи customFrame.width + 8 + 16. И, сдается мне, что все это можно было сверстать чисто на автолейаутах без кода, но это уже за рамками вопроса

Comment: Да, вы правы, я в строке `let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1000)` сделал ошибку, предоставив все свободное место по ширине. Правильный вариант будет `let size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 1000)`. Число выбрал я методом подбора.

Comment: ИМХО, это тоже не совсем правильный вариант, скорее уж надо от view.frame.width отнимать отступы справа и слева чтобы покрыть все возможные размеры экранов (а он сейчас не один даже только у айфонов)

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен.